# Checkbox Text l does not fit its text

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, resize

C# Win32:
I have a Checkbox with some text in it. but it is on one of the panels of a splitter. and I have set the auto size property to True ..but when I move the splitter bar to the left to make the space smaller it cuts off some of the text of the check box...how can i make it to still show the whole text and for example break it in two lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use word wrapping you have to set AutoSize=false . You can use Annchors or DockStyle to align it to the panel. You will have to give it enough Height.